# Strange upper() behaviour for dateranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, range-types

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4.5 and I've just got an unexpected result from this query:

```
select  upper(('[2005-12-01,2005-12-04]')::daterange)
```

It returns `2005-12-05` instead of `2005-12-04`.

The following query excludes the upper bound by specifying `)` instead of `]`:

```
select  upper(('[2005-12-01,2005-12-04)')::daterange)
```

It returns `2005-12-04`.

Isn't the `upper()` function supposed to return the upper bound limit of a given range? If so, by specifying `[2005-12-01,2005-12-04]` as the range, it should return the upper bound which is `2005-12-04`. It returns `2005-12-05` instead, which is very odd to me.

Any explanation on why this happens? I only know that `'[2005-12-01,2005-12-04]'::daterange` is translated by PostgreSQL to `'[2005-12-01,2005-12-05)'::daterange`, but this doesn't explain why `2005-12-05` should be the upper bound when I have explicitly specified `2005-12-04` as the upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'[2005-11-01,2005-12-04]'` is just another string literal for a date range to represent the canonical form `'[2005-11-01,2005-12-05)'`. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE)

> The built-in range types `int4range`, `int8range`, and `daterange` all use
>   a canonical form that includes the lower bound and **excludes the upper
>   bound; that is, `[)`**.

Bold emphasis mine.

Else you would have two equal values and `upper()` would still return a different result, which wouldn't be acceptable.

Comment: Hi Erwin, I still don't get it. `[•,•)` and `[•,•]` should have different upper bounds but PostgreSQL returns the same. I didn't use the `daterange(•,•)` notation because I knew it is translated into a range of type `[•,•)` so I explicitly specified the `[•,•]::daterange` notation. By specifying `[•,•]` I'm forcing PostgreSQL to use the `2005-12-01≤x≤2005-12-04` range, right? From my math knowledge, the upper bound of `2005-12-01≤x≤2005-12-04` is `2005-12-04` while the upper bound of `2005-12-01≤x<2005-12-05` is `2005-12-05`. May be PostgreSQL implements a different definition of upper bound?

Comment: @pietrop: The range types on discrete values mentioned in my quote are *always* transformed to canonical form internally.  I.e.: `[•,°]::daterange` is exactly the same as `[•,°+1)::daterange`, and `upper()` always returns `°+1` as (exclusive) upper bound. Follow my link and read the manual for more details.

Comment: The problem is given by the conversion from closed to opened intervals. They are both the same because they are discrete but the true upper bound really differs. PostgreSQL doesn't account for the actual definition of the interval given in the query and this leads to a wrong result from `upper()` relatively to how the interval was defined prior to the conversion. In mathematics the upper bound of `[•,°]` is `°` while the upper bound of `[•,°+1)` is `°+1`. As an example, the upper bound of `{1,2,3}` is `3`, not `4`. I'm just saying the term "upper bound" is used improperly and is misleading.

Comment: I've just found a similar discussion on the psql mailing list: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20150116152713.2582.10294@wrigleys.postgresql.org
Mathematically speaking the upper() function returns a wrong result with discrete sets. Informatically speaking it returns a correct result that responds to a naive definition of upper bound. The official documentation lacks of mathematical clearness in my opinion. I'll ask for it to be improved. Thank you for your help